# Can I put something in the <meta property="og:url" ... but use the <meta property="og:description" of another page?

Tags: send, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem.

A user will arrive on a secured page(on wich there will be the send button) wich url is always changing because it's the page of payment confirmation. In the "meta property og:description" I will put for exemple: "I've just bought a ps3 for only 100$ and a game for 50$ if you want to do like me go on www.mysite.com" The prices and objects of the cart will change. But in  the "meta property og:url..." it will always be for exemple "www.mysite.com" and on that page the "meta property og:description" will be different than the page of payment confirmation.

Is there a way to use the "meta property og:description" of the page of payment confirmation and to put in the "meta property og:url ..." the url of the site homepage?

Thanks for you're help

Answer (score 0):

You should have a landing page that Facebook can lint that has the different types of promotions on it, each with their own og tags.  Once the user lands there, you can use javascript to redirect them to your home page (or where ever).  Facebook's linters don't run javascript, so they will stand on that unique landing page and read the og tags from it.